# Replace every occurence in a file with a list elements - every next occurence with a list's next element

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, replace

Suppose, I need to replace every 's' in the file, provided I know there are three of them, replacing every occurence on occurence-per-list-element basis:

```
This is my test
```

list: `[1, 2, 3]`

Desired output after a replacement:

```
Thi1 i2 my te3t
```

What is the most elegant/pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `s`s with placeholders and use `str.format` to fill:

```
s = "This is my test".replace('s','{}')
lst = [1, 2, 3]
out = s.format(*lst)
```

Output:

```
'Thi1 i2 my te3t'
```